# How to fix "user warning: ... cache.inc on line 109." from a Drupal site?

Tags: drupal

The following message is shown on everything page of a Drupal site:

`"user warning: in /var/www/html/.../includes/cache.inc on line 109"`

Please advise how to fix (get rid of) it. Thanks!

Info: User saw that after he deleted a post.

Comment: Besides the full error message, you should also post the exact version of Drupal you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the 'how to fix it' part of the question, we need more info on the error (full message, error log entries).

As for the 'get rid of it' part, you could (and should, if it's a production site) adjust the error reporting settings to 'Write errors to the log' under `'admin/settings/error-reporting'` to prevent screen output of errors to site users.